# Custom validator in usercontrol in wizard control validation issue

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

i have a checkbox which is in a usercontrol and the usercontrol is in an wizardcontrol and the wizardcontrol is on a content page which has a masterpage.

the checkbox must be checked before the wizard controls finishes. the checkbox and the customvalidator are on the last step of the wizardcontrol.

now everything works fine with firefox and when i test it also with ie. but somehow other people may be able to go on with the proces without having to check the checkbox. 
the checkbox also has a togglebutton extender. i hope that that is not a problem.

my inline javascript (in the usercontrol)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    function ValidateTandCs(source, args)
    {
        args.IsValid = document.getElementById('<%= cbAV.ClientID %>').checked;
    } 
    // ]]>
</script>
```

the checkbox:

```
<asp:checkbox id="cbAV" runat="server"/>
```

the customevalidator and togglebutton extender

```
<asp:CustomValidator 
     ID="rfvAV" 
     Display="Dynamic" 
     runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="cbAV" 
     ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
     ClientValidationFunction="ValidateTandCs" 
     onservervalidate="rfvAV_ServerValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
<ajaxToolkit:ToggleButtonExtender 
     ID="tbeav" 
     runat="server" 
     TargetControlID="cbAV" 
     ImageHeight="15" 
     ImageWidth="15" 
     CheckedImageUrl="~/images/checkbox-on.gif" 
     UncheckedImageUrl="~/images/checkbox-off.gif" />
```

the code behind of the customvalidator

```
protected void rfvAV_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = (cbAV.Checked);
}
```

i have tried to remove the clientside validation from the customvalidator, but when i only have the server validation. it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem. it was that the javascript (clientside) didn't work in IE.
the serverside validation, validated really good. but when you click on the finishbutton of the wizard control it didn't had a page.isvalid check. so it just ignored the invalid validator. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using both a validation routine on the client side and one on the server side?

Try removing the ClientValidationFunction property on your  and keep the OnServerValidate property.

Comment: because i had before only the client side. and that doesn't seem to work in IE. therefore i added a serverside also.

Comment: And because you should never trust the client side validation if it's anything remotely sensitive. Client's can bypass things if they're a little creative. Client side validation for convenience of the client. Server side validation for security.